# node js defining a var inside a function

Tags: node.js

Could anyone explain why the flag var 've not re-defined? I'd change the flag value based on select result

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database(my.db','OPEN_READONLY');
flag = 0;
db.serialize(function(){
    db.get("select id from table where id = ?", [id], function(err, row) {
        flag = 1;
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            flag = 2;
        }
    });
    console.log(flag);
    db.close();
});
```

the output for flag var is 0, but, I need 1 or 2

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the execution is 'asynchronous' and not sequential. The anonymous callback function is getting executed after logging the `flag` variable.
You should use flag inside the callback.

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database(my.db','OPEN_READONLY');
function foo(flag) {
    if (flag == 1) {
        //no errors
    } else if (flag == 2) {
        //handle errors
    }
}
db.serialize(function(){
    db.get("select id from table where id = ?", [id], function(err, row) {
        flag = 1;
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            flag = 2;
        }
        foo(flag);
        db.close()
    })
})
```

Comment: how to handle flag value then? I need to some code weither query return some data or not

Comment: @Leo: you are welcome; if you are satisfied with the answer, can you please mark it as accepted?